# Are there any Norse stories that feature trials to claim the throne?

Tags: norse, myth-identification

I’m writing a story where the main character is the heir to a throne but has to pass 3 trials to actually claim the throne as hers.

Are there any trials that the Norse used in similar cases?

Answer (score 2):

Arguably, Norse mythology even has a god of trials, [Forseti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forseti)

The [Æsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86sir) named [Syn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syn_(goddess)) springs to mind. She guards the gates of Frigg's hall and issues trials so that only those worthy may enter. Her judgement is final.

The [Voluspá,](http://www.voluspa.org/) gives the account of the trials of Gullveig.